# visuals on screen are fuzzy after installing nvidia 340.46

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

I installed the latest nvidia driver for my GeForce GTX 650 Ti card. Everything seems to be visually ,but  it happens, the sections of my moniter start going fuzzy that makes to read text on a webpage. Anybody else having similar problems?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, sometimes some websites or programs windows started flashing. I solved the problem temporarily switching to version 331.89.

solution is here: http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-the-nvidia-331-89-gpu-drivers-on-ubuntu-14-04-ubuntu-13-10-ubuntu-12-04-and-derivative-systems/